# How do I run an sql code on submit?

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, oledb

I'm trying to figure out how I could run SQL code on submit
I wanna run

```
o_con.Open();
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter da2 = new 
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(o_command2);
System.Data.DataSet ds2 = new System.Data.DataSet();
da2.Fill(ds2, "RegisterDatabase");
if (ds2.Tables["RegisterDatabase"].Rows.Count > 0)
     {
         Response.Write("User exists!!!");
     }
o_con.Close();
```

when the submit button is pressed.
Also, I have a JavaScript function that checks that checks if the input is valid, for the username I only check if it's not blank.

```
function checkStuff() {
    var counter = 0;
    if (document.getElementById("username").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("error1").style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("error1").style.visibility = "hidden";
        counter++;
    }
```

can I make it so if the username exists, instead of the Respond.Write , error1's innerHTML changes to "User already exists", and the counter doesn't go up by 1 ? maybe include the sql code in the checkStuff function? (if that's even possible)

edit: Just realized I forgot to mention. the SQL code is in another page, because of the Request.Form, I'd rather it'll be on the same page as the registration form is, so it doesn't restart the page (because then I'll have to respond.redirect to the registration page), but I don't know if you can request the value of an input from the same page.

Answer (score 0):

submit will automaticly post your form to the page.
What you need is AJAX. Just add to your button

```
OnClientClick="CheckUserName(); return false"
```

then you will need a javascript function

```
function CheckUserName()
{
  //call function using AJAX
}
```

there are some good examples on the internet. One of them is using webmethods. You could also use the updatepanel or use CallbackEventHandlers.

Here is an example using Webmethods

[Webmethods](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx)